# Why is a flag working on command line with cmake but not inside a if(MSVC) statement in the CMakeLists file?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, cmake

I have a CMakeLists.txt file and inside it, I am using an `if(MSVC)` clause to set a flag (specifically `set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)`). However, this does not work and the generated DLL is empty.

When I set the flag in the command line, like so:

```
cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017 Win64" -DCMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS=True ..
```

it works perfectly fine and the DLL gets generated along with the LIB file. Can anyone think of a reason for this issue? Thanks!

Comment: Probably, this is about the place where you call `set(CMAKE_WINDOWS_EXPORT_ALL_SYMBOLS ON)`. But since you haven't provided the code, we could only guess. (Hint: Add the code into the question post).

Comment: If you have the check for `MSVC` before any calls to `project()`, CMake has not yet determined the compiler, and the `MSVC` variable will not yet be set.